# how to calculate incremental total amount paid everytime an amount is entered in another column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

The Total Amount is incrementing(single cell:H2) when value is entered in the same cell(G2)..e.g today if you enter in G2 the value of 30 the total amount in H2 is 30;when you enter tomorrow in G2(same cell) the value of 50, the total amount in H2 should be 80;and when you enter again 80 in the same cell(G2)the next day, the total amount should now be 160...hope you could shed a light on this...Thank you very much...

Answer (score 1):

### UPDATE:

I found this to be working, no VBA required. It should be quite simple actually. Start with your file like this:

```
|   | G           | H                 |
|---+-------------+-------------------|
| 1 | Amount paid | Total Amount Paid |
| 2 | 0           | 0                 |
```

Now go to your settings (for 2010 File -> Options -> Formulas, for 2003 Tools -> Options -> Calculation), tick 'Enable iterative calculation' and set 'Maximum Iterations' to 1. Now in `H2` enter your formula as `=G2+H2`. This is a circular reference (the simplest one there is, cell `H2` refers to itself in the calculation) which won't work properly unless you set your calculation settings right. If you set your calculation in the same settings tab to manual then the total will only update when you press F9. If you set it to automatic it will automatically update when you make a change in cell `G2`.

### Original answer

Assuming your data starts in `A1` this  formula would sum up all numbers in column `A`

```
=SUM(A:A)
```

If you won't have other stuff in this column (and don't mind the obvious overkill) this will work. If you need to be a little more specific and update a range that dynamically grows/shrinks we need to be a little bit more clever and use `INDIRECT` or `OFFSET` as follows

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("A2:A"&COUNTA(A:A)))
=SUM(OFFSET(A2,0,0,COUNTA(A:A)-1,1))
```

If you don't know these functions look into them in the Help, they can be very useful.

Another thing to clean things up would be to define a named range with the above e.g. `OFFSET` formula piece and use that in your formula(s). This makes it easier to repeatedly use the specified range and improves the readability of your formulas. I would define `PaidRange` as follows

```
=OFFSET(A2,0,0,COUNTA(A:A)-1,1)
```

and then your formula would read

```
=SUM(PaidRange)
```

Comment: The Total Amount is incrementing(single cell:H2) when value is entered in the same cell(G2)..e.g today if you enter in G2 the value of 30 the total amount in H2 is 30;when you enter tomorrow in G2(same cell) the value of 50, the total amount in H2 should be 80;and when you enter again 80 in the same cell(G2), the total amount should now be 160...hope you could shed a light on this...Thank you very much...

Comment: I see I misunderstood the question. I know it's not hard to code in VBA, you'd just put a `If Target.Address = "$G$2" Then Range("H2") = Range("G2") + Range("H2")` or something very similar (sorry I don't have Excel on this laptop). The only possible solution with formulas only I can think of is with circular references, i.e. turning calculation on Manual and setting iteration steps on 1 in settings and putting `=H2+G2` in `H2`, but I cannot test this simple-minded theory right now.

Comment: @user3682103 - see if the updated answer doesn't work for you

Comment: I've tried the formula above and it's working fine in row 2.But when i enter a value in row 3 under column G3, the value also in row 2 Column H2 changes.What i was expecting is that, when a value is entered in G2 Row 2 the total value under H2 increments and when a value is entered under G3 the total amount under H3 increments only and not affecting the value in H2.That's what's happening with the above corrections.In my table I have different names in every rows and have different amounts paid in different days.That's why I need an incremental total amount under column H.Advance thanks.

Comment: @user3682103 - This will only work for 1 row (and you didn't mention there's more rows involved in the requirements). I think this can only be solved in VBA, not with formulas.

Comment: Can you help me then Sir?It would really be of great help if you can lend a hand on this because I'm not well verse with excel Sir.

Comment: @user3682103 - [Here](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/run-macros-change.htm) is a well written, step by step introduction to the Worksheet_Change event which you'd need to use here. There is even a fine example that should get you started.